# Passing Custom Object from VB6 to Web-APi and get returned xml message

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-web-api, vb6

I am having a problem passing a custom object from vb6 to a web-api. In debug mode I can see that the correct Action method is being called in the Web-Api but the object is always null. If I just try to pass a string, it wont allow it.

a) I can call the method (if it has no parameter) no problem.
b) I can call the method (that expects an object) but the object is null. Its as if the web-api thinks nothing is being passed therefore allows me to execute the method.
c) When I call the method that expects one parameter with a string datatype it returns an error.

The Web-Api was built using .Net Framework version 4.0

VB6 Code

```
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim strServer As String
Dim strSend As String

strServer = "http://localhost:59290/api/Service/BscSignoffTaskRequestVB6"
strSend = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><sysbus><auth><key>ABC123</key></auth></sysbus>"

xmlhttp.Open "POST", strServer, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

xmlhttp.Send strSend
```

WEB-API Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage BscSignoffTaskRequestVB6(string containerObj)
    {
        try
        {
            string xml;
            xml = "THIS HAS WORKED";

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var debug = ex;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }

    }
```

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.